# Blowing Shofar at end of neilah before nightfall of Rabbeinu Tam

Tags: zemanim, yom-kippur, shofar

How do Chassidim and litvaks who hold Rabbeinu Tam's view of when nightfall is (later than most people's) blow shofar before that time after neilah?

Comment: In our Yeshiva (Sefaradi) we hold Rabenu Tam also and blew Shofar in Neila. +1

Comment: I thought sefardim kept a shorter zman.

Comment: Do you know that Chassidim and litvaks get to neilah before Rabbeinu Tam's zman?  I guess I always assumed that people who follow RT just end later.

Comment: Maran holds to keep until Rabenu Tam.

Comment: On Yom Kippur.........

Answer (score 3):

*Mishna B'rura* 623:12 says one may blow *shofar* after *n'ila* even during *ben hash'mashos* (i.e. before sure nightfall, as long as it's *safek layla*, possibly night), since, as he says there, "it's a rabbinical prohibition for the sake of a *mitzva*". Since you're asking about *Rabenu Tam*'s view, you may prefer a more hasidic source: *Shulchan Aruch Harav* :11 permits it also ("since this sounding is not a labor at all and doesn't even have a complete prohibition… and was prohibited on *Shabas* and holidays only because of 'weekday activities'"). See also *Taame Haminhagim* 773 (which does not address your question exactly but is interesting).

Comment: This would still require waiting 58 minutes after visible sunset.

Comment: In your estimation, the communities mentioned in the question blow shofar always at least 58 minutes after visible sunset?

Comment: I have little basis on which to estimate that, @DoubleAA. The last time I prayed in such a synagogue on _Yom Kipur_ was decades ago.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is complete without such an assertion, at least of a _miut hamatzui_ of those communities in quesiton.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't doubt that some hold _Rabenu Tam_'s time only _l'chumra_ (e.g. they start _Shabas_ at standard sundown) and thus should (CYLOR) be allowed to blow _shofar_ from standard sundown. Perhaps I should edit that into the answer.